# Удалить символы в строке после запятой в Python

Tags: python, текст

Есть txt файл в котором содержатся подобные строки (их 60+):

```
soler(count,min,avg,max):
grep_req_das: 10, 1, 1, 2
grep_req_says: 12, 3, 1, 30
ПРЕК.req: 20, 3, 1, 20
ПРЕК RI.req: 12, 3, 2, 80
...
```

И т.д. помогите удалить в каждой строке все, что стоит после первой запятой и саму запятую.
В итоге, чтобы получилось так:

```
soler(count,min,avg,max): 
grep_req_das: 10
grep_req_says: 12
ПРЕК.req: 20
ПРЕК RI.req: 12
```

Я использую split, но удаляется весь текст после первой запятой:

```
a_string = open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
split_string = a_string.split(",", 1)
substring = split_string[0]
print(substring)
```

Вывод:

```
soler(count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на скорую руку

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_str = f.read().splitlines() 
    print(all_str[0])
    for el in all_str[1:]:
        split_string = el.split(",", 1)
        substring = split_string[0]
        print(substring)
```

суть в том чтобы читать файл построчно и уже в каждой строке применять split

**UPD**

для записи в новый файл

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('text1.txt', 'w') as f1:
        all_str = f.read().splitlines() 
        f1.write("%s\n" % all_str[0])
        for el in all_str[1:]:
            split_string = el.split(",", 1)
            substring = split_string[0]
            f1.write("%s\n" % substring)
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, все работает!

Comment: А как теперь записать это обратно в файл? Когда я записываю substring в файл, то он пишет одну строку туда

Comment: @Resto обновил.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не додумался сам

Comment: Подскажи, как изменить твой ответ, чтобы можно было оставлять не первое число, а второе, третье, четвертое на выбор?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек:

```py
import re


with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as a_string:
    print(re.findall(r'^.+?\d+', a_string.read(), flags=re.M))

# ['grep_req_das: 10', 'grep_req_says: 12', 'ПРЕК.req: 20', 'ПРЕК RI.req: 12']
```

или чтобы записать обратно скорректированные строки:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as a_string:
    lines = re.findall(r'^.+?\d+', a_string.read(), flags=re.M)

with open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as a_string:
    a_string.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: еще б строку `soler(count,min,avg,max):` первой доавить

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin и получит неработающий код )))) Задача состояла в том, чтобы отформатировать строки и записать их обратно в файл. Или я не так понял (у меня такое случается)

Comment: ну в заголовке вопроса да) но в тексте вроде указан что хотел автор иметь на выходе, не уверен в обязательности 1 строчки) по идее не столь важно, там же были указанны что за значения выводится)