# txt файл в словарь Python

Tags: python, словари, dict

В текстовом файле лежат такие строки, это часть

```
soler(count,min,avg,max): 0
grep_req_das: 10
grep_req_says: 12
ПРЕК.req: 20
ПРЕК RI.req: 12
laik(min):
tase.dip: 1002
```

Я преобразовываю в словарь так:

```
file = open("test.txt")
onstring = file.read().split("\n")[:-1]
dict = dict()

for item in onstring:
    key = item.split(":")[0]
    value = item.split(": ")[1:]
    dict[key] = value
file.close()
```

Но на выходе значения все в квадратных скобках и кавычках:

```
{'soler(count,min,avg,max)': [], 'grep_req_das': ['10'], 'grep_req_says': ['12'], 'ПРЕК.req': ['20'] ...
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю, как сделать, что было так:

```
{'soler(count,min,avg,max)': 0, 'grep_req_das': 10, 'grep_req_says': 12, 'ПРЕК.req': 20 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# открываем файл, обязательно указывая режим и кодировку
with open(r'path\to\file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as fl:
    # считываем содержимое файлам одним списком стром
    onstring = fl.readlines()

# определяем выводной словарь. Ключевое слово dict занято классом словаря,
# поэтому его использовать в качестве идентификатора переменной не рекомендуется.
# Так же не рекомендуется напрямую инициализировать его экземпляры. Для этого
# есть соответствующий синтаксический литерал
res = {}

# проходим в цикле по списку строк
for i in onstring:
    # присваиваем переменным k и v левую и правую часть подстроки,
    # разделяя по символу ':'
    k, v = i.split(':')
    # убираем лишние концевые пробелы
    v = v.strip()
    # определяем, является ли значение переменной v числом, и если да, то 
    # преобразуем к целому числу, иначе оставляем строкой
    v = int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
    # добавляем в словарь соответствующие пары ключ:значение
    res[k] =  v

print(res)
```

Comment: Там у цифр не должно быть кавычек, я поправил недавно. Как убрать у цифр кавычки? Подскажи

Comment: внес нужные изменения

Comment: Спасибо все работает, и отдельное спасибо за комментарии)

Answer (score 0):

Мои 5 копеек (с учетом исходника приведённого Вами в предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152748/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-python) и Вашего коментария на ответ @cauf):

```py
import re

with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as a_string:
    lines = re.findall(r'^.+?\d+', a_string.read(), flags=re.M)

output_dict = {k: int(v) for k, v in [re.split(r'\s*:\s*', line) for line in lines]}

print(output_dict)
# {'grep_req_das': 10, 'grep_req_says': 12, 'ПРЕК.req': 20, 'ПРЕК RI.req': 12}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ